# Differential of smoothing operators

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, measure-theory

Following Gromov's article "Volume and bounded cohomology", given a riemannian manifold $M$, and given a covering $\tilde{M}$ with fundamental group $H \vartriangleleft \pi_1(M)$, we define a smoothing operator $\mathcal{S}$ as a smooth $\Gamma$-equivariant map $\mathcal{S}: \tilde{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{M}^+(\tilde{M})$, where $\Gamma=\pi_1(M)/H$ and $\mathcal{M}^+(\tilde{M})$ denotes the cone of the positive finite measures on $\tilde{M}$ with norm $||\mu||= \int_{\tilde{M}} |\mu|$. Then, Gromov defines the norm of the differential $D_{y}\mathcal{S}$ at a point $y \in \tilde{M}$ as $||D_y \mathcal{S}||= \sup_{\tau} ||D_y \mathcal{S}(\tau)||$ as $\tau$ runs over the unitary sphere in $T_y\tilde{M}$.; my problem is to understand how this differential is defined. In fact, it's not clear at all to me neither how the tangent space of $\mathcal{M}^+(\tilde{M})$ at a point $\mathcal{S}(y)$ is defined, since this space is not a manifold (at least in the classical sense). Thanks for your help.